# recyclerview android mix data pictures after scroll

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

i am developing and app that should show users instagram posts in a recyclerview...i get all data correctly but after i scroll my recyclerview pictures get mess up and one picture shows twice ...and other messed ups in my list.
here is my onbind View holder in recyclerview extends RecyclerView.Adapter :

```
   @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {




Picasso.with(context).

        load(imageThumbList.get(position)

        ).

        into(ivimage);

igetPositionImage.getPosition(position);




        /*imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageThumbList.get(position), ivimage);*/
count_like.setText(likeCounts.get(position));
```

and its my called up recycle view in my fragment:

```
 private void setImageGridAdapter() {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),3);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(1, dpToPx(1), true));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    RecycleListAdapter recycleListAdapter = new RecycleListAdapter(getActivity(),imageThumbList , likeCounts ,LikeGetterF.this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleListAdapter);
   Paginate.with(recyclerView , callbacks)
            .setLoadingTriggerThreshold(2).
                    addLoadingListItem(true).
                    setLoadingListItemCreator(new RecycleListAdapter(getActivity(),imageThumbList,likeCounts,LikeGetterF.this))
            .setLoadingListItemSpanSizeLookup(new RecycleListAdapter(getActivity(),imageThumbList,likeCounts,LikeGetterF.this))
            .build();

    //gvAllImages.setAdapter(new MyGridListAdapter(context,imageThumbList));
}
```

and my xml code :

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/all_media_files"
    >

    <!-- <ListView -->
    <!-- android:id="@+id/lvImages" -->
    <!-- android:layout_width="fill_parent" -->
    <!-- android:layout_height="wrap_content" > -->
    <!-- </ListView> -->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:background="#AFAFAFAF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and my item adapter xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    >



        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/profile"
            />


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="#AFAFAFAF"
                    >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:src="@drawable/like_red"
                    android:id="@+id/like_img"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/buttonSizes"
                    android:id="@+id/like_count"

                    />

                </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
        <!-- android:background="@drawable/char_02"-->



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove final for position in bind holder,

public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder,  int position) {

int adapterPos=holder.getAdapterPosition();

Picasso.with(context).

```
    load(imageThumbList.get(adapterPos)

    ).

    into(ivimage);
```

igetPositionImage.getPosition(position);

holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

```
    /*imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageThumbList.get(position), ivimage);*/
```

count_like.setText(likeCounts.get(position));

and use adapterPos everywhere in bindView holder